# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Identity "Remember Me" IsPersistent FALSE not working on chrome

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, google-chrome, cookies, asp.net-identity

I have dot net core 3.1 application using Identity Core. On Log-In Page, when mark "Remember Me" as false and logs-in, and then close the chrome browser and re-open, its still logs in. Where as it should be logged out on closing browser as I marked "Remember Me" as false. The issue occurs only on "Google Chrome", and working fine on "Microsoft Edge", "Firefox" etc.

Note: 1) I tried it with multiple PCs and multiple google accounts but still same issue on chrome. 2) "Remember Me" as TRUE is working fine

The login code is:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Login model, string returnUrl="/")
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
                model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl != "/")
                {
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    var LoggedInUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                    TempData["UserLanguage"] = LoggedInUser.UserLanguage;

                    var claimsprin = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(LoggedInUser);
                    var LoggedInUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(claimsprin);

                    var MenuVM = _dataAccessService.GetDefaultPage(LoggedInUserId).Result;
                    if (MenuVM != null)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction(MenuVM.ActionName, MenuVM.ControllerName);
                    }
                    else // else "/" is called
                    {
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
            }
        }

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Login Attempt");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I would be grateful if anybody helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Chrome, by default, is Enable `Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows`, like below, that why we found remember me not working in chrome. Disable this option, it will works fine.

[image]

In Edge, I find below setting.

[image]